# Pass ID between 2 controllers ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-routing

I'm new to programming and I need your help. I'm trying to create a simple testing application (ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC + EF). I've created 2 models (Event, Enrollment). The goal is to open the enrollment create form page with the selected `EventId` by clicking on the "Enroll" button in the `Events/Index` page. How should I pass the `EventId` to the `EnrollmentsController`? I tried to pass `EventId` in the `Events/Index` page using a form with hidden input, but I still don't know how to handle `EventId` correctly in `EnrollmentsController`.

Note: I don't wanna use `SelectList` in `Enrollment`'s `Create` method and view.

I will be grateful for any help. Thank you!

UPDATE: Thanks to @PanagiotisKanavos I finally get the EventId in the URL, but it still doesn't feed into the form input. There is "0". What could be wrong?

###### Models

```
public class Event
  {
    public int EventId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
  }

public class Enrollment
  {
    public int EnrollmentId { get; set; }

    public int EventId { get; set; }
    public Event Event { get; set; }

    [Display(Name ="First name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name ="Enrollment date")]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }
  }
```

###### `Events/Index` view

```
    @model IEnumerable<FormTest.Models.Event>

@{
  ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h1>Index</h1>

<p>
  <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
      </th>
      <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Date)
      </th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
      <tr>
        <td>
          @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
          @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)
        </td>
        <td>
          <a asp-action="Create" asp-controller="Enrollments" asp-route-id="@item.EventId" class="btn btn-primary">Enroll</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    }
  </tbody>
</table>
```

###### `Enrollments/Create` view

```
@model FormTest.Models.Enrollment

@{
  ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>Enrollment</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <form asp-action="Create">
      <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="EventId" class="control-label"></label>
        <input class="form-control" asp-for="EventId" name="EventId" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="FirstName" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="FirstName" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="LastName" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="LastName" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="EnrollmentDate" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="EnrollmentDate" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="EnrollmentDate" class="text-danger"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

###### `EnrollmentsController` Create method

```
// GET: Enrollments/Create
    public IActionResult Create(int eventId)
    {
      var newEnrollment = new Enrollment
      {
        EventId = eventId,
        FirstName = "John",
        LastName = "Doe",
        EnrollmentDate = DateTime.UtcNow
      };

      return View(newEnrollment);
    }
```

Here is the screen:
[image: enrollment/create]

Comment: Where's the controller code? Do you have a specific problem or are you asking how controllers work in general? Have you tried the [ASP.NET Core MVC tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/controller-methods-views?view=aspnetcore-5.0)? The `Controllers and Views` section shows *exactly* what you ask. `<a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Edit</a>` generates a link that calls `Edit` with the ID as parameter. You can use styles to make the link look like a button. You can pass different action names in `asp-action`

Comment: Do you mean you want to pass hidden input's value to action?

Comment: If you really need a `POST`, you can use `fetch` in the link button's `onclick` handler. If you really-really want a form, you can use [Form tag helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-5.0). For example, `asp-route-id="1234"` will pass `1234` to the `id`parameter

Comment: your hidden input is missing the `name` attribute: `<input type="hidden" value="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EventId)" />`. browsers ignore inputs without names

Comment: Hi,@CyberAnt,try to check my updated answer,your value name  in`asp-route-{value}` is not consistent to parameter name of action `Create`.

Comment: Hi, @YiyiYou, thank you so much! It works! 
guys, I really appreciate your help. I'm grateful to you. I can move a bit further again. Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use [asp-route-{value}](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-5.0),you need to make sure the value name is consistent to  the parameter name in action.Fo example,you use

```
public IActionResult Create(int eventId)
```

So that you need to use

```
 asp-route-eventId="@item.EventId"
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest option would be to *not* use a form but a link to the Enrollments controller. After all, the goal is to open the `Enrollments` page, not submit the enrollment :

```
<td>
 <a asp-controller="Enrollments" 
    asp-action="Create"
    asp-route-id="@item.EventID">Enroll</a>
</td>
```

The link can be made to look like a button with the proper Bootstrap styles :

```
<a asp-controller="Enrollments" 
   asp-action="Create"
   asp-route-id="@item.EventID"
   class="btn btn-primary" role="button" >
Enroll
</a>
```

The Controller action needs to accept the `id` as a parameter:

```
public IActionResult Create(int eventId)
{
    var newEnrollment=new Enrollment{ 
        EventId=eventId,
        ...
    };
    return View(newEnrollment);
}
```

The same routing tag helpers can be used [in a form](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-5.0) :

```
<td>
    <form asp-controller="Enrollments" 
          asp-action="Create"
          asp-route-id="@item.EventID" method="post">
        <button type="submit" value="Enroll"></button>
    </form>
</td>
```

Using a form like this is a bit weird though. This would require adding an `Index(id)` action that responds to `POST` along with the `Index(id)` that responds to `GET`.

The [ASP.NET Core MVC Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/start-mvc?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) shows how to create an application that lists Todo items, allows editing, deleting and redirecting from the list to the edit pages.

The [Tag Helpers in Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-5.0) page explains how tag helpers like `asp-controller`, `asp-action` and `asp-route-*` can be used to specify controllers, actions and parameters in a form.

Comment: The question mentions that the controller action is called `Create`. Hence, an `asp-action="Create"` may be required to route to it.

Comment: @AmalK thanks, I hadn't noticed it. I added the action

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank you very much, it is very helpful. It never occurred to me that I could pass the ID to another controller like this. Now I'm getting EventId to the URL - / enrollments / create / 1, that's correct, but I still can't get the value into the form input in the enrollments/create view. Any suggestions?

Comment: @CyberAnt what does the `Create` view look like? The new enrollment object will be the form's `Model`. You can use `<input asp-for="FirstName" class="form-control" />` to display and edit the contents of the `FirstName` property., `<input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" />` for the ID. Check the ASP.NET tutorial. You can find the code [here](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/main/aspnetcore/tutorials/first-mvc-app/start-mvc/sample/MvcMovie5/Views/Movies/Edit.cshtml)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I updated this question. Please, check it out. I really don't understand what's wrong... Thank you